How can I loop over files in folders in a directory? I want to access images to add to a ppt slide
TLDR: I have images in folders and I want to use python to add all images to a ppt slide but it gives No file or Directory error found error even though the name is exactly the same.
First I download them into the dataset folder
#downloading the images
from bing_image_downloader import downloader
df = pd.read_csv('multi-modal_market_map.csv')

for i in range(len(df)):
    co = df.iloc[i,0]
    downloader.download(co, limit=1, output_dir='dataset', adult_filter_off=True, force_replace=False, timeout=60, verbose=True, filter ="transparent")
 

It makes a folder for each company and puts an image under parent directory "dataset". So each image is for example dataset/1mind/Image_1.png
Then I'm trying to loop over the dataset folder to get into each sub folder and get the image to add to the slide.
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches

prs = Presentation()
blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)

for i in os.listdir("dataset"):
    
    if i == ".DS_Store":
        print("Not applicable")
    else:
        base = "/dataset/"+i+"/Image_1.png"
        print(base)
        left = top = Inches(1)
        pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(base, left, top)

prs.save('test.pptx')

It keeps giving me the error below, even though that is the file path. I've checked the current working directory in the loop and it's in the parent directory of dataset. Any ideas?
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dataset/Gamma/Image_1.png'


The first / in the path marks it as absolute path, beginning at the root of the file system or the drive (on Windows). You can try to remove this slash although it may be not reliable to use a relative path.

Thanks @MichaelButscher, I tried this but the same error
"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dataset/Gamma/Image_1.png'"

Is such a file in the directory?

Yes! there's a file.

Which OS do you use? Has the file exactly the name Image_1.png, including uppercase and lowercase?

Wow I figured it out after two hours - bing downloader sometimes downloads as jpgs and sometimes as pngs... so hardcoding that type won't work. Any ideas on how I can get the file without hardcoding name (take all files under the folder?)
Thanks btw

from glob import glob then glob("dataset/*/*"). The strings in the returned list do not only contain filenames but paths so you have to adapt how you filter out unwanted entries.
